# Show chart images outside of bar when they don't fit inside

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have this code [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/9yu0wenk/13/)  that renders a bar-chart with images positioned at the top of each bar.

For smaller values I don't want the image to render within the bar and would want it on top/outside of the bar.    For example, the 4th bar would show the image on top of the bar rather than inside.   Is there a clever way of adding something conditional as the bar-chart will use consistently changing data so need a way of determining which bars will show the image on the outside and which ones will show on the inside?

```js
var w = 750;
var h = 300;
var barPadding = 2;



var dataset2 = [{
    "category": "A",
    "Value": 18,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "B",
    "Value": 15,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "C",
    "Value": 13,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "D",
    "Value": 2,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "E",
    "Value": 12,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "F",
    "Value": 15,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "G",
    "Value": 20,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "H",
    "Value": 25,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "H",
    "Value": 30,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  }
]

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset2)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * (w / dataset2.length);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d.Value * 10);
  })
  .attr("width", w / dataset2.length - barPadding)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d.Value * 10;
  })


svg.selectAll(".images")
  .data(dataset2)
  .enter().append("svg:image")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * (w / dataset2.length) + 18;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d.Value * 10);
  })
  .attr("width", 40)
  .attr("height", 40)
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
    return dataset2[i].URLimage
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple conditional operator is enough here:

```
.attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d.Value * 10) - (d.Value * 10 < 40 ? 40 : 0);
})
```

As a side note, you should use D3 scales. In your particular dataset the values could be easily mapped to SVG coordinates, but that's almost never the case.

Here is your code with that change:

```js
var w = 750;
var h = 300;
var barPadding = 2;



var dataset2 = [{
    "category": "A",
    "Value": 18,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "B",
    "Value": 15,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "C",
    "Value": 13,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "D",
    "Value": 2,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "E",
    "Value": 12,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "F",
    "Value": 15,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "G",
    "Value": 20,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "H",
    "Value": 25,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  },
  {
    "category": "H",
    "Value": 30,
    "URLimage": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/92/Baseball.svg/520px-Baseball.svg.png"
  }
]

//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset2)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * (w / dataset2.length);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d.Value * 10);
  })
  .attr("width", w / dataset2.length - barPadding)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d.Value * 10;
  })


svg.selectAll(".images")
  .data(dataset2)
  .enter().append("svg:image")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * (w / dataset2.length) + 18;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d.Value * 10) - (d.Value * 10 < 40 ? 40 : 0);
  })
  .attr("width", 40)
  .attr("height", 40)
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
    return dataset2[i].URLimage
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```